# python compute sample size for one-sample Z-test

Tags: python, statistics, ab-testing

I'm trying to see if there's an easy way to calculate minimum sample size required for a one-sample Z-test to reject the null hypothesis.

I know that we can reject the null hypothesis (i.e. the A/B test is successful) if

```
1 - scipy.stats.norm.cdf((x-mu)/(s/np.sqrt(n)) < alpha
```

where x is the sample mean, mu is the population mean, s is the population standard deviation and n the sample size.

Is there a way in python to solve the equation above for `n`?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying you want to vary `n` while keeping `x` fixed?

Comment: I know all other variables and I need to solve for `n`

Comment: Ok thanks. One further clarification: you refer to a t-test but your equation implies your test statistic is normally distributed which would make this a Z-test not a t-test. I assume the equation is correct and you meant to say Z-test, but can you double check?

Answer (score 1):

Distributions in `scipy.stats` have an inverse of the `cdf` function, which is called [`ppf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf.html?highlight=ppf#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf). `ppf` stands for "percentage point function" but this is a misnomer because it actually deals with **quantiles**, not percentiles. We can use this function and the fact that `ppf(cdf(x)) = x` to rearrange and solve your equation.

Assuming that `alpha < 0.5`, there are two cases to cases to consider. If `x <= mu` then there are no solutions, otherwise we can rearrange the equation to:

```
np.sqrt(n) > s * scipy.stats.norm.ppf(1 - alpha) / (x - mu)
```

---

##### An aside:

If `alpha >= 0.5` then the solutions are strange: either any `n` will do (if `x >= mu`) or you get an **upper bound** on `n` (if `x < mu`). But that's what you get for treating your null hypothesis with such contempt!